# ECS task only able to pick one message from SQS queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have an architecture which looks like that:

- As soon as a message is sent to a SQS queue, an ECS task picks this message and process it.
- Which means that if X messages are sent into the queue, X ECS task will be spun up in parallel. An ECS task is only able to fetch one message (per my code above)

The ECS task uses a `dockerized` Python container, and uses `boto3` [SQS client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html)  to retrieve and parse the SQS message:

```py
sqs_response = get_sqs_task_data('<sqs_queue_url>')
sqs_message = parse_sqs_message(sqs_response)

while sqs_message is not None:
    # Process it
    # Delete if from the queue
    
    # Get next message in queue
    sqs_response = get_sqs_task_data('<sqs_queue_url>')
    sqs_message = parse_sqs_message(sqs_response)

def get_sqs_task_data(queue_url):
    client = boto3.client('sqs')

    response = client.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        MaxNumberOfMessages=1
    )

    return response

def parse_sqs_message(response_sqs_message):

    if 'Messages' not in response_sqs_message:
        logging.info('No messages found in queue')
        return None
    
    # ... parse it and return a dict

    return {
        data_1 = ..., 
        data_2 = ...
    }
```

All in all, pretty straightforward.

In `get_sqs_data()`, I explicitely specify that I want to retrieve only one message (because 1 ECS task has to process only one message).
In `parse_sqs_message()`, I test if there are some messages left in the queue with

```
if 'Messages' not in response_sqs_message:
        logging.info('No messages found in queue')
        return None
```

When there is only one message in the queue (meaning one ECS task has been triggered), everything is working fine. The ECS task is able to pick the message, process it and delete it.

However, when the queue is populated with X messages (`X > 1`) *at the same time*, X ECS task are triggered, but only ECS task is able to fetch one of the message and process it. 
All the others ECS tasks will exit with `No messages found in queue`, although there are `X - 1` messages left to be processed.

Why is that? Why are the others task not able to pick the messages left to be picked?

If that matters, the `VisibilityTimeout` of SQS is set to 30mins.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Feel free to ask for more precision if you want so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to give an answer to that question.

The problem was the fact the the SQS was setup as a FIFO queue.
A FIFO Queue only allows one consumer at a time (to preserve the order of the message). Changing it to a normal (standard) queue fixed this issue.

Comment: Normal = "Standard queue". Awesome spot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand how the tasks are triggered from SQS, but from what I understand in the SQS SDK documentation, this might happen if the number of messages is small when using short polling. From the `get_sqs_task_data` definition, I see that your are using short polling.

> Short poll is the default behavior where a weighted random set of machines
>   is sampled on a ReceiveMessage call. Thus, only the messages on the 
>   sampled machines are returned. If the number of messages in the queue 
>   is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested 
>   per ReceiveMessage call. 
>   If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response. 
>   If this happens, repeat the request.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message

You might want to try to use Long polling with a value superior to the visibility timeout

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The triggers is done using a Lambda. 
This indeed `If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response.` worries me a lot. Still, as it works with only one message, I wonder if it is indeed the root cause of the issue.
Will give it a try and let you know!

Comment: What did you set your long polling timeout to? Set it to the max of 20s and you should get the messages. Also, if your other hosts are not receiving the messages still, verify whether those messages are marked 'in flight' (maybe they were received by a different host)